# syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php 

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"naam\" value=\"$row['naam']\">";

}

$result->free();
?>
```

If I do `echo $row['name']`, it gives the right result, but when I wanted to put this in a HTML submit button within a form tag. It says:

> "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting
>   identifier"

I know I don't have to use a escape on the `['name']` cause I you echo in "sometext", so I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it with curly braces:

```
echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"naam\" value=\"{$row['naam']}\">";
```

Sidenote: If your string contains characters like `"` double quotes this will prematurely terminate it and break the markup, add `htmlspecialchars` to make sure before echoing:

```
$row['naam'] = htmlspecialchars($row['naam']);
```

Comment: @XavierVanVinken sure glad this helped, of course another way would be to take it oustide and instead concatenate. be careful though, if `$row['naam']` contains some double quotes it'll surely break that attribute and terminate it prematurely

Answer (score 3):

Check [string concatenation operator in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Best looking solution for me:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input type='submit' name='naam' value='".$row['naam']."'>";
}
```

or

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<input type="submit" name="naam" value="'.$row['naam'].'">';
}
```

Make sure, that You escape earlier (before outputting) some chars with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to ensure that Your code will not ruin up:

```
$naam_value = htmlspecialchars($row['naam']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code mesh up with \ and double quote

use:-

```
echo "<input type ='submit' name='naam' value='".$row['naam']."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use . because you want to concatenate the string between "" with the value of $row['naam']

```
echo "<input type =\"submit\" name=\"naam\" value=\".$row['naam'].\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type ="submit" name="naam" value="' . $row['naam'] . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

there is problem in your string:try

```
<?php 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<input type ='submit' name='naam' value='".$row['naam']."'>";
}
$result->free();
?>
```